# How to setup GoDaddy dns forwarding

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, godaddy, forwarding

I have a VPS in England and a hosting account with hostgator.
I use GoDaddy to manage my domain name settings.

My VPS is mainly used for mail and certain other services.
The actual site is hosted at hostgator

I had a cname called "www" which would point to mydomain.com, at hostgator
All the rest would point to my vps. (The "A" host, @)

Now Hostgator lost my original domain name, so pointing to that leads to a fake website.

But you can't just make www point to an ip adres. No.
I tried adding an "A" host which would point to the hostgator ip-adres and then I would point the "www" cname to that "A" host.

But that does not work. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything wrong with that situation.  Godaddy supports both A and CName records, and how you described is how those records should work.

Can you explain further what 'does not work' means?  Also, make sure that you're not fighting with caching issues.

Try out nslookup as a tool  That's very helpful.  For example:

```
nslookup
set type=ns
yourdomain.com
```

{This will give a list of the name servers.}

```
server {one of the authoritative servers}
set type=a
yourdomain.com
set type=cname
www.yourdomain.com
```